# "Cold boot: snapshot doesn't exist" when running the Android SDK Emulator for the first time

Tags: android-emulator, avd-manager

I am just new to Android Studio and I tried to run the emulator from the SDK for the first time. When I click on the Run button, the emulator opens with an error:

> Cold boot: snapshot doesn't exist.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall Intel HAXM in SDK tools and then reinstall it. you'll solved your problem.
[image]